# Spacy fails to load model : en_core_web_md in Azure databricks

Tags: azure, model, databricks, spacy, azure-databricks

So spacy seems successfully installed in Notebooks in Azure databricks cluster using.

%sh
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

I then validate it using the following command in a cell

```
%sh
```

`python -m spacy validate`

This returns the following results :

⠙ Loading compatibility table...
✔ Loaded compatibility table

====================== Installed models (spaCy v2.3.2) ======================
ℹ spaCy installation:
/databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy

TYPE      NAME             MODEL            VERSION
package   en-core-web-md   en_core_web_md   2.3.1   ✔

Therefore the medium English model appears loaded .
However when running this command

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

The following error message appears:

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below steps to install and load spaCy package on Azure Databricks.

**Step1:** Install spaCy using pip and downloading the spaCy models.

```
%sh
/databricks/python3/bin/pip install spacy 
/databricks/python3/bin/python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

**Notebook output:**

[image]

**Step2:** Running the example using spaCy.

```
import spacy

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Process whole documents
text = ("When Sebastian Thrun started working on self-driving cars at "
        "Google in 2007, few people outside of the company took him "
        "seriously. “I can tell you very senior CEOs of major American "
        "car companies would shake my hand and turn away because I wasn’t "
        "worth talking to,” said Thrun, in an interview with Recode earlier "
        "this week.")
doc = nlp(text)

# Analyze syntax
print("Noun phrases:", [chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks])
print("Verbs:", [token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ == "VERB"])

# Find named entities, phrases and concepts
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

**Notebook output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem thus :

Define Spacy library in Databricks, ensure automatic install is not selected
The blue spacy link should direct to the following : https://pypi.org/project/spacy/

Start a version 7 , ML cluster. Once started.
Navigate to the library and manually select and click install on the Cluster.

Now open notebook and run cell,

```
%sh

pip install 'jsonschema>=2.6.0,<3.1.0'
```

In next cell run

```
%sh

python -m spacy validate
```

This confirms Spacy exists on cluster but no models

In next cell install the model

```
%sh

 python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

**Validate model now exists.**

```
%sh

python -m spacy validate
```

In next cell run the following imports python code

```
import spacy

import json
```

8 . In next cell run and load ( in my case )the middle size English model , you may be loading and running a different sized model and language for your application. See Spacy website for exact name.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

9 .Finally the code that was failing now works.

Later on the code that previous errored now works.

```
row_step =20
ALL_DATA = []
for i  in  range (0,df.shape[0] , row_step) :

    start_pos = i 
    end_pos   = i  + row_step  
    print(f'{start_pos}   {end_pos}')
    text_tmp_ls   = df.iloc[start_pos:end_pos]['text'].to_list()

    ALL_DATA_tmp     = [parse_train_data_sorted(d) for d in nlp.pipe(text_tmp_ls) ]
    ALL_DATA = ALL_DATA  + ALL_DATA_tmp
    print(f'length ALL_DATA : {len(ALL_DATA)}')
```

Now Spacy is stepping through a list of texts , and processing subsets of the list 20 items at a time using using the Matcher to find entities. This avoids memory breaches a handy technique..

I believe that all shell pip commands should run before any python imports that may depend on them.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.